# Don't like my choice of grad program and don't know what to do

Tags: masters

I have a BSW (social work) and have decided to go back to school for MSW; but social work was never my passion. I honestly picked it in undergrad because they took all my credits when I didn't pass the Praxis for Early Childhood Education (missed each by 1 point) and now I'm in the MSW program at Delaware State University but hate it. I feel like I'm just wasting my time; its not something that I am interested in at all. I went back because "its the thing to do" if I want to get money in my field. I'm just lost when I'm in class because it doesn't have 100% of my attention. I am 26 years old and feel like its too late for me to be saying "I don't know what I want to do with my life." What are some other options of programs I could  look into that is somewhat within social work?

Comment: One thought...its not really unusual not to know what you want to do with your life at 26! Check out [this awesome article](http://www.chicagotribune.com/news/columnists/chi-schmich-sunscreen-column,0,5909206,full.column). Its all good advice, but my favorite quote is"Don't feel guilty if you don't know what you want to do with your life. The most interesting people I know didn't know at 22 what they wanted to do with their lives. Some of the most interesting 40-year-olds I know still don't." (My undergrad English teacher assigned this as the prompt for our final exam!)

Comment: I was 30 before I realized I wanted to get a degree in Computer Science.

Comment: I was 33 when I was definitely into Atmospheric Physics - age does not matter in a lot of cases nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you do not have the passion for the study you are in - and this will invariably affect your effectiveness to be able to succeed in the Masters you are doing.  At 26 years old, rather than being 'too late' to try anything new, take this as an opportunity to explore new fields, to find where your passions are and most of all, find a path that you will both enjoy and feel fulfilled by.

The ultimate decision is yours; however, a few things to consider:

- Just because the course is perceived as being "the thing to do", does not mean it is the best thing for you to do.
- Consider if that field is a career that you want to devote your time to in a career.
- Is there chances for innovative new research in a related field?

Comment: @Ashley, I am glad I could help - just remember, never to give up.